# EmberJS: How to trigger a parent model refresh when transitioning between children?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is my router:

```
  this.route('bundle', { path: 'bundles/:slug', resetNamespace: true }, function () {
      this.route('pricing');
  });
```

So there are two child routes: `index` and `pricing`.

Index is a listing of all the products in the bundle, while pricing is where you can purchase the bundle. When somebody purchases a bundle, the `pricing` page displays a `link-to`:

```
{{#link-to 'bundle' bundle.slug}}View Bundle{{/link-to}}`
```

This hits the `model` hook of `bundle.index`, but not of the parent route `bundle`. I need to refresh the parent route's model after a purchase though because there are server-side changes to the model that need to be displayed in the front-end.

How can I make that happen?

Comment: `didTransition` hook of `bundle` will also called when `pricing` or `index` route is loaded. I guess you can use that or else you can send an action from the child routes to the parent.

Comment: Your path definition looks weird. I don't thing your index route should have ```:slug``` in path.

Answer (score 0):

On transition hook you can ask for parent model with [modelFor](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor).

```
willTransition(){
  let model = this.modelFor('bundle');
}
```

Although it may be possible that you will have to redefine your routes because it look like your base router has path with parameter.